# Add front brake and/or improve back brake on 2012 Specialized P.24?

Tags: brakes, bmx

I love the P.24. Sometimes I like to ride it on steep offroad downhills and keep it under control. Currently, my braking strategy is brake and bail if necessary. :)

According to http://bmx-bikes.findthebest.com/l/576/2012-Specialized-P-24 the brake is: "Tektro FX-340 U-brake, melt forged, single bushing, coil spring, 15mm offset arms, soft compound pad".

I just added a longer pad, that seems to help. What else might I try to get better performance?

There is some kind of mounting hole on my front fork. What brake could I mount on there?

See also:

- Q: "Can you confirm whether the forks on the P.24 are drilled for side-pull brakes or have mounting bosses for 990/U brakes?" A: "The bike is really not designed to run a front brake. Last year we did spec some with a front U brake on the same fork, but they required a an adapter which we no longer manufacture." (From http://specialized.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/507805-p-24-front-brakes)

Updates (8/30/2013):

- I called Specialized. The person I talked to said that I could find a front brake that would probably work.
- I measured the hole as having a 6mm diameter and 35mm length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mounted a cantilever brake on the fork. It works well enough. Having twice the stopping power is nice.

I also upgraded my pads to larger ones and got rid of extra cable slack.

Also, I think my stopping power is increasing now that the black paint on the braking surfaces is wearing away, showing shiny aluminum rim instead.

Answer (score 2):

Get Odyssey cable & lever. It did magic to my BB5 5 years ago. This fork doesn't looks like it has brake mounts, so either get another fork or another (sick maybe) idea is to get actualy two bikes: MTB for offroad, 20 BMX for park and street. That's what I did eventualy.

Comment: Two bikes is a very good compromise. Optimizing one bike for "everything" is ... difficult.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the http://www.odysseybmx.com/catalog/braking/springfield-brake/ would fit on the rear.